# Why does method type inference fail to infer a type parameter?

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

I am not exactly sure how to make this question readable/understandable, but hear my out and I hope you will understand my issue when we get to the end (at the very least, it is easily reproduceable).

I try to call a method used for validating results in UnitTests. It has the following signature:

```
void AssertPropertyValues<TEnumerable, TElement, TProperty>(
  TEnumerable enumerable, 
  Func<TElement, TProperty> propertyPointer, 
  params TProperty[] expectedValues) 
  where TEnumerable : System.Collections.Generic.IList<TElement>
```

What this means is, that it takes the following input

1. Any object that is enumerable, and contains objects of the same Type as the intput for 2).
2. A Func (usually encapsulating lambda expressions) that takes an object of the same Type as the "contents" of 1) and returns an object of the same Type as the Type of the contents of the array provided in 3).
3. An array of objects of the same Type as that of the output of the Func in 2).

So, an actual execution of this method could look like this:

```
AssertPropertyValues(
  item.ItemGroups, 
  itemGroup => itemGroup.Name, 
  "Name1", "Name2", "Name3");
```

At least, that is how I would like it to look like, but I run into the well known compiler error: "The type arguments for the method 'X' cannot be inferred from the usage.", and that is what I do not understand. It should have all the info needed as far as I can see, or perhaps it is another version of the "Covariance and Contravariance" problem?

So for now I am forced to do it like this instead:

```
AssertPropertyValues(
  item.ItemGroups, 
  (ItemGroup itemGroup) => itemGroup.Name, 
  "Name1", "Name2", "Name3");
```

Can anyone point out why this scenario can not be inferred by the compiler?

Comment: have you tried to use `IEnumerable<TElement>` or sth alike instead of `TEnumerable`?  basically `propertyPointer`-parameter should be the same as the predicate eg in `Enumerable.Select`-extension method (and therefore the whole construct work alike)... which type does `item.ItemGroups` has (any missmatch, that makes the explicit signature mandatory?)? otherwise I do not get the problem you are facing...

Comment: I've fixed the formatting of your code samples so that they're reasonable and renamed your question; this has nothing to do with the lambda.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair My problem stems from that I originally had this constraint multiple places, and at some places used them as return types, and therefore couldn't "make do" with just interfaces. Not the case anymore when trying out EricLippert's solution.

Comment: @EricLippert: Isn't the fact that the second argument is an lambda expression what gave me the problem to begin with? Had I used a delegate, the compiler would have all the info needed.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the fact that constraints are not considered part of the signature and are never used to make deductions during type inference.  You are expecting the inference to go:

- `TEnumerable` is determined by taking the type of the first argument.
- `TElement` is determined by taking the `IList<T>` implementation information from `TElement`
- `TProperty` is determined by the type of the body of the lambda

But C# never makes that second step because that requires considering information from a constraint. As you note, if you provide that information in the lambda then the compiler makes the deduction based on the formal parameter type.

Fortunately your constraint is completely unnecessary. Rewrite your method to have a simpler signature that doesn't have a constraint:

```
void AssertPropertyValues<TElement, TProperty>(
  IList<TElement> sequence, 
  Func<TElement, TProperty> projection, 
  params TProperty[] expectedValues)
```

and now you should be fine.

And while you're at it, you should probably simplify that to `IEnumerable<TElement>` unless you need an `IList<T>` for some reason.

Comment: Ah, I actually thought the constraints was used. Kind of a shame that it is not. As I pointed out in the comment to my question, I could not simplify this to begin with, because of dependecies to other methods that needed the signature for return types. After some refactoring, your solution worked for me though. Thanks! :) (and yes, I need the IList but thanks for pointing it out anyways)